# global@ structures

Tags: preamble

I'm using a standard model do write my thesis. I'm stucking in a (maybe) silly problem.

[image]

I want to put some text under the examiners names. The used command is

```
\newcount\@examiner\@examiner0
\newcommand\examiner[3]{%
\global\@namedef{CoppeExaminer:\expandafter\the\@examiner}{#1\ #2, #3}
\global\advance\@examiner by 1
}

  \begin{flushright}
        \count1=0
        \@whilenum \count1<\@examiner \do {
            \vskip26\p@ \baselineskip12pt
        \eqmakebox[signture@list][c]{\hrulefill}\\
        \eqmakebox[signture@list][c]{%
            \ \ \ \protect\csname CoppeExaminer:\the\count1 \endcsname\ \ \ }\\
            \advance\count1 by 1}
  \end{flushright}
```

I did not put all the preamble commands because there are too many. I apologize if it is necessary.

I don't have enough experience to understand this structure.

Comment: Yeah, we need more information here. Unless you completely describe what you mean by "[wanting] to put some text under the examiner's names."

Comment: @Werner the ideia is to put Member 1, for example, centralized under the Ilir Snopche name and the same idea for other names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option below adds `Member #` below each `\examiner{<cred>}{<name>}{<degree>}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\makeatletter
\newcount\@examiner\@examiner0
\newcommand\examiner[3]{%
  \global\@namedef{CoppeExaminer:\expandafter\the\@examiner}{#1\ #2, #3}
  \global\advance\@examiner by 1
}
\makeatother

\examiner{Prof.}{Ilir Snopche}{Ph.D.}
\examiner{Prof.}{Slobodan Tanushevski}{Ph.D.}
\examiner{Prof.}{Francesco Noseda}{Ph.D.}

\begin{document}
  
\makeatletter
\begin{flushright}
  \count1=0
  \@whilenum \count1<\@examiner \do {
    \vskip26\p@ \baselineskip12pt
  \eqmakebox[signture@list][c]{\hrulefill}\\
  \eqmakebox[signture@list][c]{%
    ~~~\protect\csname CoppeExaminer:\the\count1 \endcsname~~~} \\
  \eqmakebox[signture@list][c]{Member~\number\numexpr\the\count1+1\relax}
    \advance\count1 by 1}
\end{flushright}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, Werner.